# Kindly assist in figuring out the logical bug in the program

Tags: c++

I tried using cout at various stages to figure but in vain. The program crashes after flushing the first two values in the reversed list. It prints a garbage value as the third value and before it can print the last two values, it crashes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LLStack {
    public:
        struct Node {
            int data;
            Node* next;
            Node(int n) {
                data = n;
                next = 0;
            }
            Node(int n, Node* node) {
                data = n;
                next = node;
            }
        };
        LLStack();
        LLStack(const LLStack&);
        LLStack& operator = (const LLStack&);
        ~LLStack();
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        int top();
        bool isEmpty();
        void flush();

    private:
        Node* head;

};

LLStack::LLStack() {
    head = 0;
}

LLStack::LLStack(const LLStack& s) {
    head = new Node(NULL);
    head->data = s.head->data;
    if (s.head->next != NULL) {
        head->next = new Node(*(s.head->next));
    }
    else {
        head->next = new Node(NULL);
    }

}

LLStack::~LLStack() {
    this->flush();
}

LLStack& LLStack::operator = (const LLStack& s) {
    this->head = new Node(NULL);
    this->head->data = s.head->data;
    if (s.head->next != NULL) {
        this->head->next = new Node(*(s.head->next));
    }
    else {
        this->head->next = new Node(NULL);
    }

    return *this;
}

void LLStack::push(int x) {
    if (head == 0) head = new Node(x);
    else {
        Node* temp = new Node(x, head);
        head = temp;
    }
}

int LLStack::pop() {
    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements to pop\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        Node* temp = head;
        int n = temp->data;
        head = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        return n;
    }
}

int LLStack::top() {
    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the stack\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return head->data;
    }
}

bool LLStack::isEmpty() {
    return (head == 0);
}

void LLStack::flush() {

    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the Stack to flush\n\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n\nFlushing the Stack:  ";
    Node* temp = 0;
    while (head != 0) {
        temp = head;
        cout << temp->data << "  ";
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void reverseStack(LLStack& s1) {
    LLStack s2;
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s1.pop());
    }
    s1 = s2;
}

int main() {

    LLStack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
    s.push(4);
    s.push(5);
    reverseStack(s);
    cout << "\n\nFlushing s:\n";
    s.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

Please run it and you'll understand. I'm extremely depressed because of this. Please help.

Comment: when reversing the stack shouldn't you change the head too.? your method `reverseStack` doesn't change the head.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't matter as we're returning a new stack with elements reversed. We're not working on the same linked list.

Comment: in `flush()` you are using head which actually pointing to the last element. As it reversed in `reverseStack` so in while loop you will get only the first then it will get 0 i guess if you don't change the head

Comment: Brother Saif, the reversed list has it's own new head. It's a whole new linked list.

Comment: Parenthood has been really tough for me man. My programming skills have dropped.

Comment: Imagine being a father at 21. Anyways, do you think the problem is with the copy constructor?

Comment: got your point. sorry i missed the head check ` if (head == 0) head = new Node(x);` in  `push()` . You are right.

Comment: Can you please ask someone to find the bug? Some people here donot answer any questions.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question contains an MCVE and a clear description of the problem.

Comment: Same homework problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/28998341/981959 -- do we mark the other one as a dup of this, since it has a copy ctor? @SoutheeRocks, see my comment on the other question about implementing the assignment operator

Answer (score 2):

Your copy constructor and assignment operator don't look correct to me. They only copy two nodes, `head` and `head->next`. What about the rest of the stack? The copy of `next` will still point at whatever it was pointing to before. If the original is deleted, like when `s2` goes out of scope at the end of `reverseStack`, it will be left pointing at a deleted `Node`.

You also need to consider what to do with the existing state of the stack in the assignment operator.

The easiest way I can see to fix your code is to not use the copy constructor or assignment operator at all. I would explicitly delete them until you have them working:

```
LLStack(const LLStack&) = delete;
LLStack& operator=(const LLStack&) = delete;
```

But it is easy to [write a `swap` function](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-throwing_swap) for your stack:

```
void LLStack::swap(LLStack& rhs) {
  std::swap(head, rhs.head);
}
```

Then you can use it in `reverseStack` instead of the assignment operator:

```
void reverseStack(LLStack& s1) {
  LLStack s2;
  while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
    s2.push(s1.pop());
  }
  s1.swap(s2);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

remove `delete temp;` from `void LLStack::flush() {}`

```
void LLStack::flush() {

    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the Stack to flush\n\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n\nFlushing the Stack:  ";
    Node* temp = 0;
    while (head != 0) {
        temp = head;
        cout << temp->data << "  ";
        head = head->next;
       // delete temp; //delete
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Based on the fact that `flush()` is called in the destructor, I'm assuming its main responsibility is to delete the nodes in the stack and the output is just for debugging purpose. If you remove the `delete` you are introducing a memory leak. Not deleting anything is not a good way of avoiding dangling pointers.

Comment: It is still risky to do the deletion in a public member function even if it's not the OP's problem. For conceptual correctness, the deletion should be moved from `flush` to the destructor.